# Contar quantidade de meses que "Viraram" a partir de duas datas?

Tags: php

Preciso contar a quantidade de meses que ***viraram*** a partir de duas datas utilizando `PHP`, eu possuo o seguinte código para calcular a diferença de meses entre 2 datas.

```
$data1 = '2017-01-01';
$data2 = '2017-03-01';

$date = new DateTime($data1); 
$diferenca = $date->diff(new DateTime($data2));
$diferenca_anos = $diferenca->format('%Y')*12;
$diferenca_meses = $diferenca->format('%m');

$total_meses = $diferenca_anos+$diferenca_meses;

echo $total_meses;
```

O código funciona bem quando as datas estão bem separadas, porém meu problema ocorre quando quero comparar duas datas como.

```
$data1 = '2017-06-20';
$data2 = '2017-07-01';
```

No caso acima meu código retorna 0, meses porém preciso que ele conte como se tivesse "virado" um mês (de Junho para Julho), da mesma forma se eu utilizar.

```
$data1 = '2017-06-20';
$data2 = '2017-08-01';
```

precisam ser contabilizados 2 meses.

Alguém possui alguma sugestão?.

Comment: Então não importa o dia? Vc quer saber apenas o número de meses que entraram na jogada?

Comment: No caso de `$data1 = '2017-08-01';` e `$data2 = '2017-09-01';`, oque deveria voltar?

Comment: Deveria voltar 1 no caso da passagem do mês 08 para o mês 09.

Comment: Mesmo ignorando os 30 dias passados entre as datas?

Comment: Isso mesmo, quantidade de dias não é interessante, eu só preciso saber quantos meses "viraram" de acordo com o início e fim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que o intervalo mostra o tempo entre as datas, acredito que para o resultado desejado, deva calcular manualmente a diferença em meses, assim temos:

```
<?php
$data1text = '2017-06-01';
$data2text = '2017-07-21';

$date1 = new DateTime($data1text);
$date2 = new DateTime($data2text);
//Repare que inverto a ordem, assim terei a subtração da ultima data pela primeira.
//Calculando a diferença entre os meses
$meses = ((int)$date2->format('m') - (int)$date1->format('m'))
//    e somando com a diferença de anos multiplacado por 12
    + (((int)$date2->format('y') - (int)$date1->format('y')) * 12);

echo $meses;//2
```

Nesse código assumo que as datas sempre virão certas, caso seja invertido as datas, a $data1text seja maior que $data2text ele retornara um valor negativo, pode-se tratar isso usando o abs()

```
 <?php
 $data1text = '2017-06-01';
 $data2text = '2017-05-21';
 [...]
 echo $meses;//-1
 echo abs($meses)//1;
```

Assim terei o valor absoluto entre as datas.

[SandBox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e375d5e02c1f12f8b2c691605f82ffb9c6aa0f4c)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @MarcosPaulo Esta resposta não funciona quando a segunda data for "2017-08-01". Retorna 2.

Comment: @Dvdsamm quais datas?

Comment: A última da pergunta.

Comment: @Dvdsamm parece que faltou algo na sua conta, 2017-06 para 2017-08 é 2, ou me enganei?

Comment: Ah tah. O rapaz que perguntou alterou. Antes estava "3".

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que seria somente subtrair o mês com o o outro mês, em geral isso:

```
function MesesVirados(string $inicio, string $fim){

    return abs($fim['mes'] - $inicio['mes']);

}
```

Logo isso funcionária subtraindo os meses, assim temos:

```
De '2017-01-01' para '2017-03-01' => 03 - 01 => 2
De '2017-06-20' para '2017-07-01' => 07 - 06 => 1
De '2017-06-20' para '2017-08-01' => 08 - 06 => 2
```

Existe um problema nisto, que é em relação aos anos, porque afinal `2016-12-01` para `2017-01-01` dará uma diferença de 11 meses. Para corrigir isso somasse 12 aos anos diferentes, assim teríamos `12 - (01 + 12) = 1`.

---

Logo poderia simplesmente fazer isso de qualquer maneira, a lógica acima poderia ser escrita da seguinte forma:

```
function ExtrairData(string $data) {
    $data = explode('-', $data);

    if (count($data) !== 3 || !checkdate($data['1'], $data['2'], $data['0'])){
        return false;
    }

    return array_combine(['ano', 'mes', 'dia'], $data);
}


function CorrigirMeses(array $inicio, array $fim) {
    return ($inicio['ano'] - $fim['ano']) * 12;
}

function MesesVirados(string $inicio, string $fim){
    $inicio = ExtrairData($inicio);
    $fim = ExtrairData($fim);

    if (!$inicio || !$fim){
        return "Ocorreu um erro";
    }

    return abs($inicio['mes'] - $fim['mes'] + CorrigirMeses($inicio, $fim));
}
```

[**Teste isto.**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/12f438c72e734242c2799dd21a61ae7b9c69a107)

---

Se quiser um código menor, sem qualquer validação de `checkdate` e tal, baseado na resposta do @Gregorio bonfante:

```
$data1 = array_combine(['y', 'm', 'd'], explode('-', $data1));
$data2 = array_combine(['y', 'm', 'd'], explode('-', $data2));

$meses = abs($data1['m'] - $data2['m']) + (($data1['y'] - $data1['y']) * 12);
```

Comment: Realizei alguns testes e parece ter funcionado muito bem. Porém irei escolher a resposta abaixo pois ela ser mais simples de implementação.
Obrigado pela ajuda.